# Symfony, entity vs repository

Tags: symfony

I'm new to Symfony, I come from a MVC framework where there were just one **Model** class, but here in Symfony we have 2, as far as I've learnt (**Entity** and **Repository**)

So, I'm not sure when a method should be put inside the Entity class and when it should be inside the Repository...

for example:

```
$user->logLogin()
```

which logs the user login (timestamp, ip, country, user agent ecc.) to a log_logins table, and it's called from a login event listener, where should it go? (I'm not going to create a UserLogins Entity since there is no need to manipulate the data on that table, it's just some read-only information)

Comment: In few words... An entity is a representation of a table in your application, so put on an entity all methods related with properties of it, e.g: `$user->getEmail()` . A repository is a way to retrieve entities, so put on repositories any method you need to get them, such as `getUserByEmail` or whatever.

Comment: Table `log_login` is connected with table `user` by relation many to one. Tou can use doctrine relations and in `user` entity include method `addLogLogin()`. In `user` entity, there will be property `logLogin` with type `ArrayCollection`. It is desctibed in [doc](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)

Answer (score 18):

It might not be immediately evident, but in Symfony you do things with *services*. The login method does not belong either in the entity or the repository.

The general idea is as follows:

- Entity: a data structure. Almost never has a meaningful method that is not an accessor.
- Repository: The only part that interacts with a DB. You use the default ones in most cases but do need one if you have some special queries. Business logic should not be here either.
- Services: where the business logic lives. Have a lot of them. Make them use other services and repositories

A typical controller invokes a few services, usually without touching repositories (or Doctrine) directly.

This structure is not apparent in many examples that cut out some of these layers in the interest of being as simple and brief as possible.

NOTE: Symfony has a rich login system which is already connected to several of its components and that you might use without without reimplementing a new one. I'd reccomend to have a look.

Comment: as I understood it, the repository is for reading from the DB. But for inserting an entity (new, set, flush, commit), where does this go? [The docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#persisting-objects-to-the-database) put that code in to the controller.

Comment: Usually they go in a service. The examples in the documentation often put clarity first so they are minimalistic and do not represent a typical use case.

Answer (score 2):

Entity and Repository are two completely different things.  A Repository is not a Model.  The Entity represents your Model.  The Repository interfaces to the database.  More than likely your previous framework used an active record approach as opposed to the data mapper approach which Doctrine 2 uses.  It will require some rethinking.

To answer your question, logLogin updates the database so not only does it go into the repository but it **can't** go in the entity for the simple reason that the entity has no connection to the database.

So you would inject the repository into your listener and then, when a login event comes around you do:

```
$this->userRepository->logLogin($user);
```